# Laravel Broadcast Notification error : Client can not be authenticated, got HTTP status 404

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-echo, laravel-broadcast

I am trying to build a real-time notification system.
I used Laravel-Notifications and laravel-echo-server.
when I listen for notification using start command in terminal laravel-echo-server start then error occured in private channel:

> ⚠ [4:36:43 PM] - H12aWYBsF5UdR5NYAAAH could not be authenticated to private-App.Domain.User.User.1
>
> Client can not be authenticated, got HTTP status 404

**CODE**

// channels.php

```
Broadcast::channel('App.Domain.User.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;});
```

// Notification file code (ListingApproved.php)

```
class ListingApproved extends Notification implements ShouldQueue {
use Queueable;

private $listing;

/**
 * Create a new notification instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(Listing $listing)
{
    $this->listing = $listing;
}

/**
 * Get the notification's delivery channels.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['database', 'broadcast'];
}

public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return $this->listing->id;
}
public function toBroadcast($notifiable)
{
    return new BroadcastMessage([
        'invoice_id' => $this->listing->id
    ]);
}}
```

//front-end script to listen for notification

```
Echo.private('App.Domain.User.User.' + '{{ auth()->user()->id }}')
        .listen(".Illuminate\\Notifications\\Events\\BroadcastNotificationCreated", (notification) => {
            console.log('yes');
            console.log(notification.type);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be related your echo server `auth host` configuration,

You can check for example laravel real time application with laravel echo server and redis,

[Real time application example with Laravel / Redis / Socket.IO / Laravel-Echo](https://github.com/durmus-aydogdu/real-time-application)

I hope this will help

Comment: I share this link for example. Did you check your conf with shared example ? You have problem with auth host link and example consist of this usage, for this please check , `https://github.com/durmus-aydogdu/real-time-application/blob/master/resources/assets/js/UserEvents.js` and `https://github.com/durmus-aydogdu/real-time-application/blob/master/laravel-echo-server.json.example` and readme